# C# Generics: How can I declare a generic where 2 collections have to contain the same type but the collections needn't be of the same type

Tags: c#, generics

I need a class generics signature for `T`, where `T` must be an IEnumerable of of any kind, but that which in in the IEnumerable, may not.

In a nutshell:
`HashSet<int>` and `HashSet<string>` are never allowed, but `HashSet<int>` and `List<int>` are allowed.

I currently have this signature:

```
namespace Foo {
        public interface IOperator<in T, out TResult> { }
        public abstract class AbstractOperator<T, TOutput> : IOperator<T, TOutput> { }
        public abstract class LogicalOperator<T> : AbstractOperator<T, bool> { }
        public sealed class IntersectionOperator<T> : LogicalOperator<T> where T : IEnumerable<T> { }
}
```

And I have this test:

```
var op = new IntersectionOperator<HashSet<string>>(); //compile error
var setA = new HashSet<string> { "Hello", "World" };
var setB = new List<string> { "Goodbye", "World" };
            
Assert.True(op.Apply(setA, setB)); // compile error
```

The first error is:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0311  The type 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<string>' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'IntersectionOperator<T>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<string>>'.
```

The second error is:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<string>'   Gatekeeper.Test
```

Can this be done?

Comment: The class doesn't need the IEnumerable constraint nor the HashSet argument, just <string>. Then make the parameters of Apply as (IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<T>).

Comment: You can't create a constraint in C# the way you're trying to do it.

Comment: @CodeCaster - the super type will accept any 2 `T`, so I can't do that.

Comment: @Enigmativity - So, I just need to leave it as object? I mean, that will be fine because the underlying implementation will behave correctly

Comment: I don't see a super type having two generic parameters. Perhaps create a [mre].

Comment: I just updated with the entire hierarchical structure. Hopefully that should be enough to answer the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the only way that this works for me:

```
void Main()
{
    var op = new IntersectionOperator<string>();
    var setA = new HashSet<string> { "Hello", "World" };
    var setB = new List<string> { "Goodbye", "World" };

    bool result = op.Apply(setA, setB);
}

public interface IOperator<in T, out TResult> { TResult Apply(T x, T y); }
public abstract class AbstractOperator<T, TOutput> : IOperator<T, TOutput>
{
    public abstract TOutput Apply(T x, T y);
}
public abstract class LogicalOperator<T> : AbstractOperator<T, bool> { }
public sealed class IntersectionOperator<T> : LogicalOperator<IEnumerable<T>>
{
    public override bool Apply(IEnumerable<T> x, IEnumerable<T> y) =>
        x.Intersect(y).Any();
}
```